# How to change background color of a single row inside a table with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to modify the color of each row inside a table only if the text content inside the 4th cell is equal to "DELAYED"
I maked a function to do that but no color changing...

```
function assignColor()
{
    //getting all the tr elements from document
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        //Accessing to text Content in the 4th cell of the tr
        if(x[i].cells[3].textContent == "DELAYED")
        {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }

}
```

i think it's something wrong with the way i populate the table from js to html

```
function printFlights(arrayOfFlight)
{
    //I insert tr till the length of an array
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfFlight.length; i++)
    {

        //creating tr element
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");

        //Inserting cells inside tr using propertys of an object

        tr.insertCell(0).innerHTML = 
        formatDate(arrayOfFlight[i].arrivalDate);
        tr.insertCell(1).innerHTML = 
        formatTime(arrayOfFlight[i].arrivalDate);
        tr.insertCell(2).innerHTML = arrayOfFlight[i].destination;
        tr.insertCell(3).innerHTML = arrayOfFlight[i].status;
        tr.insertCell(4).innerHTML = arrayOfFlight[i].airplane;
        tr.insertCell(5).innerHTML = arrayOfFlight[i].gate;

        //add tr to tbody
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add html code of the table to the post.

Comment: Let's see the html. Can you make a full example snippet for us?

Comment: Your code works fine with a simple table, see here http://jsfiddle.net/y8w92oq7/1/. Something else is wrong, please post the HTML of your table.

Comment: May be there are additional css style for TR or TD which sets the background?

Comment: @AlexS. there are not any style sheet

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working:

```js
function assignColor()
{
    //getting all the tr elements from document
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        //Accessing to text Content in the 4th cell of the tr
        if(x[i].cells[3].textContent == "DELAYED")
        {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }

}
assignColor();
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>DELAYED</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, with one exception - if the `<td>` elements in your HTML have any whitespace in them (like this demo below), then your code needs to [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the content of the cells before the string comparison.

See below:

```js
function assignColor() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].cells[3].textContent.trim() == "DELAYED") {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}

assignColor();
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 3
    </td>
    <td>
      DELAYED
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way, it will check for Delayed regardless of the cell number.

```js
function assignColor() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('tr td');

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].textContent == "DELAYED") {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>DELAYED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>DELAYED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>DELAYED</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```